# Joomla 3 - Use Box Plus outside of article content

Tags: joomla

I would like to use the boxplus-lightbox extension for Joomla (http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/multimedia/multimedia-display/16555). Unfortunately, it can only be used in articles as far as I can see. Do you know if there's any chance to activate it outside of articles, e.g. in a module?

Thanks in advance,

enne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its has a plugin feature - {boxplus}Link text{/boxplus}

So:

1. Try inserting it as a custom html module - {boxplus}Link text{/boxplus}
2. Alternatively use the article anywhere plugin: http://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/articlesanywhere - which enables you to insert articles into modules.
3. Or another ARTICLES EMBED extension:
   http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/articles-display/content-embed

I just created it using a custom module.

Using Custom HTML Module
In J3.1:

1. Go to: "Extensions > Module Manager"
2. Click "New"
3. Choose "Custom HTML"
4. Select Module Position
5. Under "Options" Tab: "Prepare Content" -> make sure it is Yes
6. Under "Custom" Tab paste:
   {boxplus theme=lightsquare href=images/joomla_black.gif}Link text{/boxplus}
7. Save
8. Refresh page - if it shows only text then check step 5

Comment: Hi iamrobert, thanks for your help. Sounds good, but I don't know how I should use article anywhere module to insert the plugin?

Comment: I revised the answer above - as you can use custom html - I just did it

Comment: Nice and clear answer. Thanks for your response, works perfect!